# Selective Formatting Using Regular Expression

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a pretty complex but well-formatted HTML string with lots of links in it. Part of my task is to convert all anchors into bold having the word "XX1". Is this possible to do in PHP without using jQuery/js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` for this, try:

```
preg_replace('/(<a.*>.*XX1.*<\/a>)/imU', '<b>${1}</b>', $html);
```

Didn't test the pattern, should work though.

Comment: Did it some other way but what the heck? Accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Did test the pattern in the meantime and it seems to work, maybe there are some special cases that didn't cross my mind where it fails?